# 500 Internal Server Error in Akka Scala server

Tags: scala, server, akka, akka-http

This is my code for the server written using Akka framework:

```
case class Sentence(data: String)
case class RawTriples(triples: List[String])

trait Protocols extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit val sentenceRequestFormat = jsonFormat1(Sentence)
    implicit val rawTriplesFormat = jsonFormat1(RawTriples)
}

trait Service extends Protocols {
    implicit val system: ActorSystem
    implicit def executor: ExecutionContextExecutor
    implicit val materializer: Materializer

    val openie = new OpenIE
    def config: Config
    val logger: LoggingAdapter

    lazy val ipApiConnectionFlow: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Any] =
        Http().outgoingConnection(config.getString("services.ip-api.host"), config.getInt("services.ip-api.port"))

    def ipApiRequest(request: HttpRequest): Future[HttpResponse] = Source.single(request).via(ipApiConnectionFlow).runWith(Sink.head)

    val routes = {
        logRequestResult("akka-http-microservice") {
            pathPrefix("openie") {
                post { 
                    decodeRequest{
                        entity(as[Sentence]){ sentence =>
                            complete {
                                var rawTriples = openie.extract(sentence.data)
                                        val resp: MutableList[String] = MutableList()

                                for(rtrip <- rawTriples){
                                    resp += (rtrip.toString())
                                }
                                val response: List[String] = resp.toList

                                println(response)
                                response
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

object AkkaHttpMicroservice extends App with Service {
    override implicit val system = ActorSystem()
    override implicit val executor = system.dispatcher
    override implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

    override val config = ConfigFactory.load()
    override val logger = Logging(system, getClass)

    Http().bindAndHandle(routes, config.getString("http.interface"), config.getInt("http.port"))
}
```

The server accepts a `POST` request containing a sentence and returns a json array in return. It works fine but if I am making requests to it too frequently using parallelized code, then it gives 500 Internal server error. I wanted to know is there any parameter which I can set in the server to avoid that (number of ready threads for accepting requests etc).

In log files, the error is logged as:

> [ERROR] [05/31/2017 11:48:38.110]
>   [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6]
>   [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(default)] Error during processing of
>   request: 'null'. Completing with 500 Internal Server Error response.

Comment: Look into Server log Files for more Informations

Comment: Do you get a more complete stacktrace for debugging within the framework code?

Answer (score 2):

The doc on the `bindAndHandle` method shows what you want:

```
/**
 * Convenience method which starts a new HTTP server at the given endpoint and uses the given `handler`
 * [[akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow]] for processing all incoming connections.
 *
 * The number of concurrently accepted connections can be configured by overriding
 * the `akka.http.server.max-connections` setting. Please see the documentation in the reference.conf for more
 * information about what kind of guarantees to expect.
 *
 * To configure additional settings for a server started using this method,
 * use the `akka.http.server` config section or pass in a [[akka.http.scaladsl.settings.ServerSettings]] explicitly.
 */
```

`akka.http.server.max-connections` is probably what you want. As the doc suggests, you can also dig deeper into the `akka.http.server` config section.

Comment: Do I have to make some change in the `application.conf` file?

Comment: Can you check the updated question? I  have added log output

Comment: Yes, you could configure that in `application.conf`. As per your update, it rather seems that it is the code sending the request that has a problem... at least the server claims it is receiving a `null` request, or a request containing `null`.

Comment: But in the request code I am making sure that it doesn't send empty request.

Answer (score 0):

Add following in application.conf file

```
akka.http {
  server {
    server-header = akka-http/${akka.http.version}
    idle-timeout = infinite
    request-timeout = infinite
  }
}
```

Comment: @Nilesh How changing timeouts will help?